# Show Full Data Set behind Graphs when connecting to SQL Analysis Services in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

We have a live connection to a tabular 2014 edition of SQL Analysis Services model not a multidimensional one.

How can we enable the tabular model to show full underlying data in Tableau when trying to export the full dataset behind the graphs we produce?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that this is a Feature of Tableau. The exported data will only ever show exactly what is shown on the charts. (Ie: Names of Bars on bar chart and their associated aggregation.) Have you tried this using a non-cube datasource (something basic like Excel) and gotten it to display underlying (non-aggregated) underlying data?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the worksheet where your chart is you can click on Worksheet on the top menu, then click on Export, and if you select data it will put the data
in an Access database. Or you can send it in a crosstab format to Excel.

Also, if you make a duplicate copy of the chart worksheet and then in the new duplicate worksheet click on "Show Me" on the right, and click on the first option for "Text Table" and it should
format it as data if you need to see how it looks in Tableau before exporting.

Comment: Sorry, I tried all suggested approaches but only got the name of the Dimension and the total values for each.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry about that. It sounds like you would need access to the underlying data from the data source coming from SSAS. The data must have been already aggregated in SSAS when it was fed to Tableau, therefore you cannot get to the details. You need to get to the data before it was fed into SSAS (I think?).